# how to import jetcd in a java playframework project using sbt

Tags: java, playframework, sbt, etcd

I would like to use *jetcd* (https://github.com/coreos/jetcd) in our Java playframework project that uses sbt. I haven't figured out how to successfully import *jetcd* as a dependency and was wondering if anyone could post a sample config showing all the steps?

thanking you in advance
Francis

Comment: please note that the jetcd project I'm referring to is https://github.com/coreos/jetcd. There are many jetcd projects our there so don't chose the wrong one please

Answer (score 2):

`coreos/jetcd` does not seem to have been published to a public repo, yet. You can do this:

Clone and build the project locally:

```
git clone https://github.com/coreos/jetcd.git
cd jetcd
mvn install -DskipTests
```

Within your project, add to `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.coreos" % "jetcd" % "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal
```

That does it for me, using Scala and `sbt`. I added an [issue](https://github.com/coreos/jetcd/issues/66) to their GitHub project, including a link to this question.

Answer (score 0):

## Identify the Dependency

The first thing do is find out the specific dependency you need. Searching for 'jetcd maven dependency' we get to [this page](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.floatingsun/jetcd/0.3.1). Clicking on the `SBT` tab we get the following dependency configuration snippet:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.floatingsun/jetcd
libraryDependencies += "net.floatingsun" % "jetcd" % "0.3.1"
```

## Configure `build.sbt`

Assuming you're using a simple build file (no sub-projects, meta-builds or similar), you should be able to drop that line straight into your `build.sbt`. Sometimes it might also be configured like this:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  ...  // a list of other dependencies
  "net.floatingsun" % "jetcd" % "0.3.1",
  ...  // more dependencies
)
```

## Validate

Once you've placed the dependency in your project as above, build SBT (from the command line `sbt compile`). Open up a file in your project and attempt to import a `jetcd` class:

```
import com.coreos.jetcd.EtcdClient;
```

If that works, you're good to go. If there is an error somewhere along the way it should describe what went wrong.

Comment: this is not the correct jetcd project. That's why I linked the git project url in my question. That being said, can you formulate your response again with the correct jetcd project ?

Comment: You can; you may need to find a specific maven repo that is publishing it, if it's not the main one. If you need to add a resolver (that is, a place for SBT to look for dependencies) you can do something like `resolvers += "CoreOs" at "https://someplace.org/repo"`. The `CoreOs` and `https://someplace...` would have to be filled in with valid values.